# Resolving a dead lock between two gen_tcp

Tags: erlang, gen-server

While browsing the code of an erlang application, I came across an interesting design problem. Let me describe the situation, but I can't post any code because of PIA sorry.

The code is structured as an OTP application in which two `gen_server` modules are responsible for allocating some kind of resources. The application runs perfectly for some time and we didn't really had big issues.

The tricky part begins when one the first `gen_server` need to check if the second have enough resources left. A `call` is issued to the second gen_server that itself call a utility library that (in very very special case) issue a `call` to the first gen_server.

I'm relatively new to erlang but I think that this situation is going to make the two gen_server wait for each other.

This is probably a design problem but I just wanted to know if there is any special mechanism built into OTP that can prevent this kind of "hangs".

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT : 
To summaries the answers : If you have a situation where two `gen_server`s `call` each other in a cyclic way you'd better spend some more time in the application design.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a deadlock and could/should be avoided at a design level. Below is a possible workaround and some subjective points that hopefully helps you avoid doing a mistake.

While there are ways to work around your problem, "waiting" is exactly what the `call` is doing.

One possible work around would be to spawn a process from inside A which calls B, but does not block A from handling the call from B. This process would reply directly to the caller.

In server A:

```
handle_call(do_spaghetti_call, From, State) ->
    spawn(fun() -> gen_server:reply(From, call_server_B(more_spaghetti)) end),
    {noreply, State};
handle_call(spaghetti_callback, _From, State) ->
    {reply, foobar, State}
```

In server B:

```
handle_call(more_spaghetti, _From, State) ->
    {reply, gen_server:call(server_a, spaghetti_callback), State}
```

For me this is very complex and superhard to reason about. I think you even could call it spaghetti code without offending anyone.

On another note, while the above might solve your problem, you should think hard about what calling like this actually implies. For example, what happens if server A executes this call many times? What happens if at any point there is a timeout? How do you configure the timeouts so they make sense? (The innermost call must have a shorter timeout than the outer calls, etc).

I would change the design, even if it is painful, because when you allow this to exist and work around it, your system becomes very hard to reason about. IMHO, complexity is the root of all evil and should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: Yeah, this make the spaghetti plate a little expensive ;). While I see clearly the workaround mechanism, I think that this definitely be avoided in my case (I'm sure you'll agree if you see the spaghetti code I'm seeing right now ;)). I'll definitely vote for a redesign.

Answer (score 3):

It is mostly a design issue where you need to make sure that there are no long blocking calls from gen_server1. This can quite easily be done by spawning a small fun which takes care of your call to gen_server2 and the delivers the result to gen_server1 when done.

You would have to keep track of the fact that gen_server1 is waiting for a response from gen_server2. Something like this maybe:

```
handle_call(Msg, From, S) ->
  Self = self(),
  spawn(fun() ->
    Res = gen_server:call(gen_server2, Msg),
    gen_server:cast(Self, {reply,Res})
  end),
{noreply, S#state{ from = From }}.

handle_cast({reply, Res}, S = #state{ from = From }) ->
  gen_server:reply(From, Res),
  {noreply, S#state{ from = undefiend}.
```

This way gen_server1 can serve requests from gen_server2 without hanging. You would ofcourse also need to do proper error propagation of the small process, but you get the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it, which I think is better, is to make this (resource) information passing *asynchronous*. Each server reacts and does what it is supposed to when it gets an (asynchronous) `my_resource_state` message from the other server. It can also prompt the other server to send its resource state with an `send_me_your_resource_state` asynchronous message. As both these messages are asynchronous they will never block and a server can process other requests while it is waiting for a `my_resource_state` message from the other server after prompting it.

Another benefit of having the message asynchronous is that servers can send off this information *without* being prompted when they feel it is necessary, for example "help me I am running really low!" or "I am overflowing, do you want some?".

The two replies from @Lukas and @knutin actually do do it asynchronously, but they do it by a spawning a temporary process, which can then do *synchronous* calls without blocking the servers. It is easier to use asynchronous messages straight off, and clearer in intent as well.

Comment: Thank you for you're answer :) it seems interesting and can fit perfectly in the OTP way of doing things I think. I'll try something using this approach and update my post accordingly.